# Calculate percentage of points within land cover classes QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, statistics, land-cover, land-classification

I am working on a project for my university and this is my first solo project.

I have a land cover classification with 6 classes. I also have a set of points that are recorded sightings of a mammal we have been observing. I have imported these points into QGIS using their lat/long and now have them overlaid on top of my land cover classification. I now want to understand in which land cover classes these points/sightings have occurred.

**If there are around 1000 points, how do I understand what percentage of them have occurred in *each* land cover class?**

For example, if there were 12 points in areas classed as "urban" then this would equate to 1.2% of sightings of the animal being in urban areas.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Modify `pt.cat` for the name of your category field as well as the name of the layers.

You can then persist the layer if you wish.

```sql
WITH tot (select count(*) as cnt from myPointLayer pt)
select p.cat, 
    100.0 * count(*) / cnt as pcnt
from tot, myPolygonLayer p
join myPointLayer pt
 on st_intersects(p.geometry, pt.geometry)
group by p.cat
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And is this the only method or most simplest method do you know? As I'm not familiar with some of the terms used.